# NavigationLink doesn't fire after FullScreenCover is dismissed

Tags: swiftui

I have a button in a view (inside a `NavigationView`) that opens a full screen cover - a loading screen while some data is processing. When the cover is dismissed, I want to automatically route to the next view programmatically. I'm using a `NavigationLink` with a tag and selection binding, and the binding *value* updates when the cover is dismissed, but the routing doesn't happen unless I tap that same "open modal" button again.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct OpenerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: OpenerViewModel
    
    @State private var selection: Int? = nil
    @State private var presentLoadingScreen = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondScreen(), tag: 1, selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.frequency = 0
                self.presentLoadingScreen.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Open cover")
            }).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Nav title", displayMode: .inline)
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presentLoadingScreen, onDismiss: {
            self.selection = 1
        }, content: ModalView.init)
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Howdy")
          .onAppear {
              DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
              }
          }
    }
}
```

The first time I hit the Button, the cover opens. Inside the cover is just a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` which dismisses it after 2 seconds. When it's dismissed, the `onDismiss` fires, but then I have to hit the button again to route to `SecondScreen`.

Any ideas?

Edit: Added the modal's View

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

Comment: I'm on Xcode 12.3 and iOS 14.3 and it's not working.

Comment: worked fine with 12.3 and iOS 14.3. How you dismiss the fullscreen?

Comment: In the fullscreen's onAppear, I run `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` 2 seconds and it calls `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`. And the `.fullScreenCover` is firing `onDismiss` as I can print out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working with some changes to the code, and I'm sharing here along with what I think is happening.

I believe the problem is a race condition using a `@State` boolean to toggle the cover and the navigation. When the cover is being dismissed, my main `OpenerView` is being recreated - to be expected with state changes. Because of this, I try to set the `@State var selection` to trigger the navigation change, but before it can do so, the view is recreated with `selection = nil`.

There seem to be two ways to solve it in my case:

1. Move the cover boolean to my view model - this worked, but I didn't want it there because it only applied to this view and it's a shared view model for this user flow. Plus, when the modal is dismissed, you see the current `OpenerView` for a brief flash and then get routed to the `SecondScreen`.
2. Keep the cover boolean in `@State`, but trigger the navigation change in the button immediately after setting the boolean to open the modal. This worked better for my use case because the modal opens, and when it closes, the user is already on the next screen.

Comment: To avoid redraws you can implement the Equals protocol on the views where it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I was trying to draw a view after dismissing a fullScreenCover. I kept getting an error that said that the view had been deallocated since it was trying to draw to the fullScreenCover.

I used Joe's hints above to make this work. Specifically:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    viewToShow()
}
```

I had previously tried onChange, onDisappear, onAppear - but none of those fit the use case I needed.